# $wpdb->get_results leaking memory

Tags: plugins, database, debug, memory

I have developed a wordpress plugin that reads large custom xml files and imports the information as custom post types and a lot of post meta information. So I am calling a lot of database transactions. The plugin runs for several minutes within one POST'ed process and then aborts with out of memory (250 MB).

Tracking the problem down to a minimum I have a minimal example that shows the problem. This example is leaking about 18 kbyte and this is summing heavily up during runtime of the plugin. The query checks if a post with a given title exists (`$title`)

```
echo "<p>memory: " . memory_get_usage() . "</p>";
global $wpdb;
$poststable = $wpdb->prefix."posts";
$items = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $poststable WHERE post_title='$title'");
unset($items);
$wpdb->flush();
echo "<p>memory: " . memory_get_usage() . "</p>";
```

The output is
    memory: 80777008
    memory: 80795376
so the difference is about 18 kbyte. Where are those bytes? Although this is a small amount of memory it is summing up to several hundred megabytes.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Try it with $wpdb->get_var  And difference?

Comment: unfortunately same result and exactly same amount of memory leaking

Comment: I tried running your code, what I got is:
memory before: 13393888 
memory after: 13392888.
Do you have any plug-ins that could be interfering with `$wpdb` ? Also you could try checking memory usage before `flush()` and before/after `get_results()` to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 3):

@IlmarsL: thanks! I really did not think of that. I had the plugin Query Monitor enabled and this was the problem... Turning Query Monitor off solved the problem and memory did no more longer increase.